# MonoGame: Añadir una clase nueva

Tags: c#, game

estoy aprendiendo Monogame con Visual Studio 2017.

Estoy en la fase de crear clases para los sprites, el problema es que sigo el patrón clásico para añdir clases (como lo haría por ejemplo en una biblioteca de clases o en una aplicación de consola) con "Añadir nuevo elemento" -> "Clase" y aunque se añada la clase al proyecto, éste no lo reconoce.

Aquí dejo la clase `Nave.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Xna;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

public class Nave
{
    private string _imagenNave;
    private int _posicionNaveX;
    private int _posicionNaveY;
    private float _velocidadNave;

    public Nave()
    {
        ImagenNave = "";
        PosicionNaveX = 0;
        PosicionNaveY = 0;
        VelocidadNave = 0;

    }

    public Nave(string nombreSprite, int posicionX, int posicionY, float velocidadNave)
    {
        ImagenNave = nombreSprite;
        PosicionNaveX = posicionX;
        PosicionNaveY = posicionY;
        VelocidadNave = velocidadNave;
    }

    public Nave(Nave nave)
    {
        ImagenNave = nave.ImagenNave;
        PosicionNaveX = nave.PosicionNaveX;
        PosicionNaveY = nave.PosicionNaveY;
        VelocidadNave = nave.VelocidadNave;
    }

    public string ImagenNave { get => _imagenNave; set => _imagenNave = value; }
    public int PosicionNaveX { get => _posicionNaveX; set => _posicionNaveX = value; }
    public int PosicionNaveY { get => _posicionNaveY; set => _posicionNaveY = value; }
    public float VelocidadNave { get => _velocidadNave; set => _velocidadNave = value; }

}
```

He probado:
- Añadirle el mismo namespace al que está `Game1.cs`

- Añadir en el `Game1.cs` el using hacia ésta clase
- En `Nave.cs` he intentado usar clases de XNA como Vector2, no las reconoce.
- He llegado a copiar/pegar en el mismo proyecto el Game1.cs y el comportamiento es igual que `Nave.cs`.
- No existe o no encuentro la opción "Añadir al proyecto", se que a veces ese es el problema.
- He probado sin exito añadir la clase a traves de Pipeline Tool.

PD: Curioso que no exista la etiqueta de Monogame.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos la estructura de clases de tu proyecto? Muéstranos también el código de error que te aparece cuando haces una instancia a la clase `Nave`.

Answer (score 0):

He descubierto que debido a la conexión con GIT, se me ha desmoronado el proyecto y no me reconocía correctamente las rutas.

No obstante, VisualStudio me hacía hincapié en que la clase debía estar definida como internal y bajo el namespace de Game (cosa lógica):

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace tema1_1
{
    internal class Nave
    {
        private string _imagenNave;
        private Vector2 _posicionNave;
        private Vector2 _velocidadNave;

        public Nave()
        {
            ImagenNave = "";
            PosicionNave = new Vector2(0, 0);
            VelocidadNave = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

La estructura del proyecto quedaría tal que así:

```
Solucion
  |-> csproj
     |-> Properties
     |-> Referencias
     |-> Content
        |-> Content.mgcb
     |-> app.manifest
     |-> Game1.cs
     |-> Icon.ico
     |-> **Nave.cs**
     |-> Program.cs
```